# Suppress Console.WriteLine for portion of program

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline

For some reason unknown to me, the developer of a library I am using has decided to `Console.WriteLine` tons of information whenever a method is called within the library, essentially explaining every step of what is going on.

This is fine, but during development I don't need to be seeing this all of the time, so my question is can I suppress `Console.WriteLine` from being used when I don't want it to be? I still wish to be able to see my own `Console.WriteLine`s, but not the ones within the Library.

Goes without saying I do not have source for the library.

Regards,

AK

Comment: Are you sure it's Console.WriteLine rather than some configurable logging library which happens to use Console.WriteLine? If this is a commercial library, I'd ask the vendor. If it's an internal library, I'd ask the team. If it's an open source library, you should have the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Console.SetOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) to redirect `Console.Out` to something of your choosing (e.g. something that discards all input) before calling into that library and then do the same to set the original value back. It's going to be awkward to do that all the time though.

To make things a bit more manageable, you can create another class that implements `IDisposable` and use it like this:

```
using(new StandardOutSink()) {
    // call into the third party library
}
```

The constructor of `StandardOutSink` (which you need to write) would redirect the output stream to a specially-crafted `TextWriter` (which you also need to write) and then the `Dispose` method would set it back to the original stream.

Comment: Not only the only solution, but also a very neat one! Thank you.